# AppHarbor basic questions on architecture and realibility

Tags: appharbor

AppHarbor looks very appealing for our .NET solution. But I have some questions I could not find on internet.

Our major concern is reliability of dedicated SQL Server:

1. Is it clustered / mirrored / replicated?
2. What happens when they upgrade / patch / maintain server or. hosted server and when hardware fails?
3. Are upgrades scheduled?
4. Can we set time interval when they do upgrades?
5. Which version and edition of Sql Server is used?
6. Can I use full text search?
7. Can I use Reporting service?
8. Is communication with SQL database reliable? For example in Azure SQL it is recommended to build in retry logic - if command does not succeed, retry.
9. Is AppHarbor reliable? Every cloud provider has occasionally some blackouts (Amazon, MS Azure ...). Is AppHarbor any less reliable compare to them? I know AppHarbor  runs on top of Amazon.
10. Are there a lot of hidden issues you run into? What are the most common?
11. Did anybody decide to leave appHarbor for a good reason?
12. As far I can see Azure is a real cloud system with all the downside and upside - more scalable, but with modified infrastructure like customized SQL server .... AppHarbor mimics  more on-premises solution. Is my understanding correct?
13. How is documentation?
14. How is support?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes AppHarbor offers redundant/replicated dedicated SQL Server databases. These plans are available upon request.
2. This depends on the type of maintenance/update and your SQL Server database plan. If the database server is replicated, downtime can be minimized by failing over to the replica while performing maintenance. In the event of a server failure the database will be attached to a new instance and the application's configuration will be automatically updated. Should a hard drive fail leading to corrupted/lost data AppHarbor make daily backups that will be used to restore your database. It should be noted that hard drive failures are very rare.
3. We generally coordinate planned maintenance that requires downtime with customers whenever possible. Dedicated SQL Server customers can also select their own maintenance window.
4. Not really, but AppHarbor will reach out and coordinate with you when it is necessary.
5. Different SQL Server versions and editions are used depending on the plan. For single-instance dedicated SQL Servers we generally use SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition. Dedicated SQL Server 2012 instances are available upon request. Replicated setups require other and more expensive SQL Server editions. You may also want to consider our dedicated MySQL service if you'd like to reduce costs and don't rely on SQL Server specific features - since AppHarbor doesn't have to pay license costs these are less expensive, particularly for a replicated setup.
6. Yes.
7. Not by default, but we can work with you to support reporting services on your dedicated SQL Server instance.
8. Yes. In fact the primary reason customers upgrade from shared to dedicated SQL Server is for consistent, reliable performance.
9. I'd say so. The last major outage occurred on July 29th, 2012 due to an [electrical storm that affecting multiple availability zones in AWS's North Virginia region](http://aws.amazon.com/message/67457/). As an example, our blog has been available 99.997% of the time since then. In the event of an application instance failure applications are rapidly moved to healthy instances. We recommend running with at least two workers to ensure redundancy in those cases.
10. I'm admittedly not the best person to answer this question. The most common request/limitation we hear about is that you can't currently trigger a backup yourself. This will be available at a later time, but we do keep daily backups of your databases.
11. -
12. AppHarbor's cloud application platform is relatively similar to Azure in terms of scalability. We support rapid "elastic scaling" of application workers both vertically and horizontally. With regards to the dedicated SQL Server service your understanding is correct: It is very similar to an on-premise solution. While the scaling story is different compared to SQL Azure this allows for much greater flexibility. We can tailor a database plan and server that suits your requirements whether you need high CPU, RAM and/or I/O performance. Similarly we can offer database sizes that are 10x larger than SQL Azure's current 150GB database size limitation.
13. Most documentation is available in the [knowledge base](http://support.appharbor.com/kb). We try and keep this as up-to-date and comprehensive as possible, but if you find yourself missing some information you're of course more than welcome to let us know and we'll add it. Third party add-on providers typically maintain their own AppHarbor-specific documentation.
14. This is another question where I may be a little biased, but I can tell a little about our goals: Our goal is to always answer non-critical support requests related to apps on both free and paid plans within the day. Critical support requests and supports requests related to applications or databases on paid plans take priority. Support is included in the plans, but we're working on offering premium support options as well. We generally try to exceed your expectations and are always happy to help out and give advice on issues you experience - whether they're related to the AppHarbor platform or not.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of AppHarbor.